# Add CMS page to main menu

Tags: magento-1.9, menu

How can I add any **CMS page to the main navigation** in Magento RWD theme? I am aware of the URL rewrites that can be done through catalogue but there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with **Fabian Blechschmidt**. Without any extension,it's not possible.

### But there is an alternative

Basically, we use ***cms page*** for ***cms content management***.

As per as my knowledge,there is a process in ***category system*** where you can manage **cms content**.

Just create ***a cms static block***   and assign that `static block` to category from ***Display setting tab***.

Then,set ***Display Mode*** as ***Static block only***. Do not assign any products to that category.

[image]

Comment: This should be marked answer. Nice answer

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative if you don't have a lot of CMS pages to add would be:

- Create a category
- Create your cms page
- Create an URL rewrite that redirects your category to your cms page.

Thus, you will have a link in the menu and that link would redirect to your CMS page.

Example:

Category:

- Name: About Us
- URL Key: about-us
- ID: 4

CMS page:

- Name: About Us
- URL Key: about-us

URL Rewrite:

- Type: Custom
- ID Path: about-us
- Request path: catalog/category/view/id/4
- Target path: about-us/
- Redirect: Permanent

Comment: Well, this works but the URL in menu shows as catalog/category/view/id/4. How to show the URL as about-us?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You can't add a CMS page out of the box to the main menu, only categories.

The alternative is to install one of plenty menu extensions.

Comment: Any free ones around Fabian that are compatible with the latest version?

Comment: I have no clue about this, it is frontend. I'm a backend guy :-(

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Is there nothing I can do in top-menu.phtml to include a CSS page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851235/how-do-i-add-pages-to-menu http://www.isummation.com/blog/add-cms-page-links-to-top-navigation-in-magento/ http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html

Answer (score 1):

Goto **Catalog-> URL rewrite Management** and search for id  in the ID path column.

Then open it and change the *redirect option* from No to **Permanent(301)**. Also copy the text inside Target Path non-editable field. It may look like this `catalog/category/view/id/50`.

Then Click save.

Then for redirecting this category page to CMS page, we’ve to add new URL rewrite.

To do so, Click Add URL rewrite button in **Catalog->URL rewrite Management**.
It’ll take you to Add New URL rewrite Screen, Where you’ve to choose **Custom** from **Create URL Rewrite** drop-down list.

It then will take you to another new page where you’ve to enter ID path, Request Path and Target Path.

ID path — It must be any unique identifier. It can anything like iamrookie or whatever  as you wish.

Request Path — It must be the Target path which we’ve copied before `catalog/category/view/id/50` in step1.

Target Path — It should be the CMS page URL Key which you want to redirect. For example *gift*.

Then select Redirection to **Permanent(301)** from the drop-down and click save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do small modification in the topmenu.phtml file of your current theme. Here is the complete description for your solution. 
You can reorder the category menu and cms page menu with the solution.
http://subodhdhukuchhu.com.np/customizing-the-magento-top-menu/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps as given in the below link:

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html